# How to scrape only one specific ul with Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm trying to get only the second `ul` element of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_8, which is all the events list.

This is what I have right now:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_8', {ssl_verify_mode: 0}))

doc.css('ul').each do |link|
  puts link.content
end
```

The UL that I need is the second one present in the whole HTML document. How can I select only that one?

Comment: When you use `css`, `xpath` or `search`, you receive a NodeSet back. A NodeSet acts like an Array, so you can use slicing and/or indexing to retrieve specific elements just as you can iterate over the individual elements. If you run `nokogiri  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_8` at the command-line it'll drop you into an IRB session where you can easily play with the DOM that was parsed, which would have let you quickly figure this out. Also, give serious look at Wikipedia's API instead of scraping; It's very powerful and less fragile than scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
doc.css('ul')[1]
```

or if you want to use CSS selectors only

```
doc.css('ul:nth-of-type(2)')
```